# Is there a way to include "@" in the user when establishing a smb connection with NtlmPasswordAuth using Java?

Tags: java, smb, ntlm-authentication

I have a username which has an @ in it and I want to establish a smb share connection (host OS: MacOS).
Lets say I have:
user: blabla@bla
pass: passw0rd

```
String url = distribution_path;
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, user, pass);
    SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(url, auth);
    for (SmbFile f : dir.listFiles())
    {
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    }
```

Comment: i am getting "cifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect", i googled it and it may be because I have a newer smb than supported (only smb1.0 supported).

Comment: Please include all details in the question than in separate comment.